# Echo multiple variables via single command in Bash

Tags: bash, sh

I would like to write the individual variables `$my_<1 to 3>_web` to the terminal, without having to manually write into script like `echo $my_1_web`, `echo $my_2_web` and `echo $my_3_web`.

Example of manual typing commands to terminal (or writing commands into script).

```sh
my_1_web="some value1"
my_3_web="some value2"
my_2_web="some value3"
echo "web at $my_1_web
$my_2_web
$my_3_web"
```

Would that be possible, approach like this? If so, I would love for an answer.

```sh
my_1_web="some value1"
my_3_web="some value2"
my_2_web="some value3"
echo "web at $my_1-3_web"
```

I'm learning bash and I'm a new member of the GNU / Linux community. I apologize if a similar case happened somewhere ...

Comment: `echo web at $my_{1..3}_web`? (do not quote `{1..3}` or *brace-expansion* will be suppressed) You can also do `echo web at $my_{1,2,3}_web`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin **Thanks! Works!!** (i am new in linux and bash xd)

Comment: Glad it helped. Note -- while you "can" use brace expansion to "piggy back" variable expansion of similar names, that doesn't mean you "should" do it. I'd much prefer to simply write all the variables out inside the double quoted string to prevent surprises if used in a context where word-splitting will cause problems. With `echo` alone that isn't a problem, but there are many places where it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably be easier to use an array instead of numbered variables:

```
my_web=(
    "some value1"
    "some value2"
    "some value3"
    )
```

Then to print them like you want:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; echo "web at ${my_web[*]:0:3}")
```

This temporarily sets the "internal field separator" to a newline so that when we join the array elements (`my_web[*]`), it joins them on the newline. I'm also explicitly selecting the first three elements, but you don't actually need to do that in this case since those are the only elements that exist.

Note that Bash arrays are 0-indexed.

*<sub>Due credit to [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s now-deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72062257/4518341) for inspiring this `echo` command.</sub>*

Comment: To explain that parameter expansion: join the elements of the my_web array starting at _index_ 0 for a _length_ of 3 elements. This also works to extract substrings: `s="Hello World"; echo "${s:3:5}" #=> "lo Wo"`

Comment: @glenn Ah oops, I thought it was like Python slicing. I changed the explanation so it's no longer misleading, though now it's vague, but that's not super relevant to the question I don't think. Thanks!